# How get max value from result of group_concat mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the max value from the result of group_concat.

Here is sample data, and what I  have tried,

```
+----+---------+--------------------------+
| id | user_id | comment                  |
+----+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 |      80 | I don't need it any more |
|  2 |     222 | Don't need this account  |
|  3 |      80 | I have an other account  |
|  4 |      80 | The other comment        |
|  5 |     222 | some x                   |
+----+---------+--------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I tried the following query,

```
mysql> select max(group_concat(id  SEPARATOR ' ')), user_id from userapp_accactivitylog;
```

But it is giving me error

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

With `group_concat(id)` We will get the result `1,2,3,4,5` . My requirement is that I want to select greatest number from the result I get with group_concat.

I hope you understand what I am looking for, please let me know if there is a way to achieve the following result:

```
+----+---------+--------------------------+
| id | user_id | comment                  |
+----+---------+--------------------------+
|  5 |     222 | some x                   |
|  4 |      80 | The other comment        |
+----+---------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I am trying to group by user_id and I want to fetch the largest number of record in the id column (i.e. 5 in this case).

Comment: Why not just use `max(user_id)`?  Can you edit your question and provide desired results?

Comment: I know max(user_id), but in my use case I need something like what I am trying

Comment: @naveentamanam But why? :-(

Comment: @Strawberry: I got what I am looking for, "Gordon Linoff"  gave me the perfect answer what I was looking for.

Comment: @naveentamanam Questions and answers on SO should benefit the entire community, so it's helpful if you can explain why you think you need this unconventional solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get what you want:

```
select
  user_id,
  max(id) as id,
  substring_index(group_concat(comment order by id desc SEPARATOR '|'), '|', 1)
from
  userapp_accactivitylog
group by user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like it works. I have edited the query you have given cause there is syntax error regarding group_concat. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) question, which is asked frequently.

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(id) AS id 
    FROM userapp_accactivitylog 
    GROUP BY user_id) AS t
JOIN userapp_accactivitylog AS u USING (id)
```